# How to Read cookiee in VB6 by hitting on a URL

Tags: vb6

I am trying to read cookiee by hitting on a url in VB 6.
Please help me out as i have searced a lot on this and not able to find out the solution for this.

Comment: What does this have to do with Android and programming?

Comment: ohh..it was done by mistake

Comment: It's not that clear (to me) what this situation is. Are you talking about sending a request to a remote server and then reading a cookie set in the response? Or implementing some form of back end component that a server is calling into when it *receives* a request, and you need to obtain the cookie? Or something else?

Comment: Actually i have a url on that url if i hit on that cookiee gets created of my id from which i have login to my system now i want to read that cookiee so that i can use it for getting further responses..

Comment: What component you are using for "hitting" url?

Comment: That is the main issue iam facing right now as i have to hit a url without opening the browser so that my cookies get created but not able to find the right method to do so...Arvo

Comment: Anyone can solve this issue

Comment: @Nischal: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unless you edit your question, it's most likely to be closed because it is very unclear what you're asking. Also, it helps to show a code sample of what you've tried. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i was looking for hitting the url without opening it in browser to get cookie information stored on that url....

Thanks to all for there comments..

```
Const scUserAgent = "API-Guide test program"
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3
Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD = &H80000000
Const sURL = "url"
Dim TargetUrl As String
Dim hOpen As Long
Dim hFile As Long

Dim abc As String


TargetUrl = "url"
hOpen = InternetOpen(scUserAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
hFile = InternetOpenUrl(hOpen, sURL, vbNullString, ByVal 0&, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, ByVal 0&)

abc = GetCookies("url", "CookieName")
MsgBox "The cookie= " & abc
```

Comment: Missing code for `GetCookies()` seems to be from here: http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19158. But it doesn't seem to work for me. :(